# Tridion: Binary components do not get deployed when published in bulk

Tags: tridion, tridion2009

I am using Tridion 5.3.

I have webpage that has over 100 pdf links attached to it. When I publish that page not all pdf get published even though I get a URL for each pdf like `"/pdf/xyzpdfname_tcm8-912.pdf"`. When I click on those links I get a 404 error. For the same pdf components for which I get the error, if I publish them by attaching 5 to 10 pdf at a time they get published and there is no 404 error and everything works fine. But that's not the functionality I need. Does any one know why Tridion is not able to deploy the binary contents if I publish them in bulk?

I am using `engine.PublishingContext.RenderedItem.AddBinary(pdfComponent).Url` to get the pdf url.

Comment: OK, good to hear that you found the cause of the problem. Can you please put the original question back though, since now the question and answers don't match anymore. While the problem may be solved for you, we want to make sure those who stumble upon this page later also know what happens and how to solve it.

Comment: Comment from @Sunil: "I think the problem is not due to the number of pdf components, but due another error.
I checked the logs and took a look at an error thrown.

I'm assuming this error blocks other pdfs from getting published. How do I modify the deployer to ignore this error, since I know this error arises when I try to republish the same component."

Comment: The source of the issue appears to be this error: A processing error occurred processing a transport package Attempting to deploy a binary [Binary id=tcm:8-755-16 variantId=tcm:8-755 sg= path=/www.mysite.com/multimedia/pdfname_tcm8-765.pdf] to a location where a different binary is already stored Existing binary: tcd:pub[8]/binarymeta[755]

Comment: You can't really modify the deployer to not throw an error here. You will need to use a different AddBinary() Override to make sure you are not trying to store different files in the same location. I have a post on this here: http://www.urbancherry.net/blogengine/post/2010/02/09/Unique-binary-filenames-for-SDL-Tridion-Multimedia-Components.aspx

Comment: @ChrisSummers, @frank, @nuno: I published my page again with and without the `variantID parameter in the AddBinary() method`, the page contains about 16 pdf components and I got following results:(1) `10- pdf failed with VariantID, but worked fine without variantID.` (2) `2- pdf failed without VariantID, but worked fine with variantID.` (3) `4- pdf worked fine in both cases.` Can you please suggest me a common solution, because I want the same AddBinary() method to work for all these pdf components and everything is in a loop?

Comment: It is impossible to answer this without knowing the error message. It seems like you have name conflicts. Do some of the binaries have the same file names?

Comment: @ChrisSummers: The error that I get while having variantId parameter in AddBinary() is something like this- `A processing error occurred processing a transport package Attempting to deploy a binary [Binary id=tcm:8-838-16 variantId=tcm:8-838 sg= path=/www.mysite.com/multimedia/mypdf_tcm8-838.pdf] to a location where a different binary is already stored Existing binary: tcd:pub[8]/binarymeta[838]`.

Comment: @ChrisSummers: The error that I get while not having variantId parameter in AddBinary() is something like this- `A processing error occurred processing a transport package Attempting to deploy a binary [Binary id=tcm:8-15065-16 variantId= sg= path=/www.mysite.com/multimedia/my_pdf2_tcm8-15065.pdf] to a location where a different binary is already stored Existing binary: tcd:pub[8]/variant[tcm:8-15065]/binarymeta[15065]`. The other thing is that these pdf components are already published in `www.mysite.com/multimedia/` through other `Component Templates/Pages`. No 2 components have same name.

Comment: OK, so your problem is that you can not have two variants of the same Multimedia Component in the same location in the Broker (pretty obvious if you think about it). So if you declare an additional variant (do you really need a different one) for a binary that is already published you will need to put it somewhere else. You can achieve this by binding it to a different Structure Group or creating a new file name. If you don't need a different variation of a binary (which would be odd for a PDF rather than a resized image), then just be consistent in all your templates and use the same variant.

Comment: @ChrisSummers : I am planning to create new pdf components and will now follow a standard way of publishing them with a standard variant ID in my templates. This way I hope I will not face this problem for publishing the new binary components. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could this be to do with the naming of your PDF?

Tridion has a mechanism in place to prevent you from accidentally overwriting a binary file, with a different binary file that is named the same.

I can see the Binary you are trying to deploy has the ID:

```
tcm:8-755-16
```

and you are naming it as follows:

```
/www.mysite.com/multimedia/pdfname_tcm8-765.pdf
```

Using the Variant Id:

```
variantId=tcm:8-755
```

is it possible you are also publishing the same binary from a different template? Perhaps with the same filename, but with a different Variant Id?

If so Tridion assumes you are trying to publish two 'Variants' of the same binary (for example a resized image, obviously not relavent for PDFs)

The deployer is therefore throwing an error to prevent you from accidentally overwriting the binary that is published first.

You can get round this in 2 ways:

1> Use the same variant ID for publishing both binaries

2> If you do want to publish a variant, change the filename to something different.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I am publishing the component from a different template in a different page. I tried the first option that u mentioned "1> Use the same variant ID for publishing both binaries". But still I get the same error. Since both the templates are using the same file I am not thinking of renaming it.

Comment: I also got another error for an image component:- `A processing error occurred processing a transport package Attempting to deploy a binary [Binary id=tcm:8-10898-16 variantId=tcm:8-10915 sg= path=/www.mysite.com/multimedia/testImage_tcm8-10898.jpg] to a location where a different binary is already stored Existing binary: tcd:pub[8]/variant[tcm:8-10898]/binarymeta[10898]`

Comment: Do you have access to your broker database? Select all rows that have a BINARY_ID that match the one you are having trouble with. Then take a look at the VARIANT_ID and URL columns, and hopefully this will help explain the deployer error?

Comment: The broker databse is the file system. I published my page again with and without the `variantID parameter in the AddBinary() method`, the page contains about 16 pdf components and I got following results:(1) `10- pdf failed with VariantID, but worked fine without variantID.` (2) `2- pdf failed without VariantID, but worked fine with variantID.` (3) `4- pdf worked fine in both cases.` Can you please suggest me a common solution, because I want the same AddBinary() method to work for all these pdf components?

Comment: Since you do not want variants of your Binaries (as they are PDFs) it may make sense to use something common for your variant id. Perhaps the publication tcm id would be a good candidate. This will work fine for all new PDFs, but any existing ones (ie any you have already published with the old variant id) you will still have problems with unless you un publish them all first. As you don't have a broker database, the data about the published binary files will be on the file system, in a location defined by your broker config file.

Comment: I am planning to create new pdf components and will now follow a standard way of publishing them with a standard variant ID in my templates. This way I hope I will not face this problem for publishing the new binary components. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the log files for your transport service and deployer. If those don't provide clarity, set Cleanup to false in cd_transport_conf.xml, restart the transport service and publish again. Then check if all PDFs ended up in your transport package.

Answer (score 2):

engine.PublishingContext.RenderedItem.AddBinary(pdfComponent).Url gives you the URL of an item as it will be published in case of success, not a guarantee that it will publish.

Pretty sure you're just hitting a maximum size limit on your transport package.

PS - Check the status of your transaction in the publishing queue, might give you a hint

After you updated the question:

There's something terribly wrong with the template and/or your environment. The Published URL says "tcm8-7**6**5.pdf" but the Item Uri is "tcm:8-7**5**5".

Can you double check what's happening in here?